# Print Server, Drivers and pop-ups?

Tags: network-printer

When sharing a bunch of printers from Windows Server's Print Server role, am I to install a special driver on the Print Server itself or same as the clients?

One printer I share, it's driver shows a pop-up window with tons of printer detail every time the printer does a job.  What is annoying is this window appears on the Print Server as well, so if I'm working on things it appears.

Am I misunderstanding some fundamental element here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a more generic printer driver instead, as they usually don't have all the extra pop-ups and junk, and tend to play nicer with networked printer setups such as you're describing.

For example, if it's an HP use the [HP Universal Print Driver](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/solutions/business-solutions/printingsolutions/upd.html), if it's another make, use their version (ie: [Xerox Global Print Driver](http://www.office.xerox.com/software-solutions/global-printer-driver/enus.html)).

If your printer's manufacturer doesn't offer a "universal" driver that works for your printer, then check the downloads page for your printer model, and look for an alternative driver labelled something like "Print Driver Only", which should be less determined to install extraneous utilities.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution, however general drivers don't allow you to leverage all the advanced functionality of the device.  Any ideas on finding a happy medium?  I don't care for print pop-ups, but I still want end-users to be able to use print overlays, finisher abilities like the stapler, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're at the mercy of your printer manufacturer to decide what features get put into their various drivers.  Also, I've seen plenty of "generic" drivers that offer most functionality via the printer options, just without the client-side utilities/popups, so it's still worth giving them a look see. ;)